# EF Code first database generation

Tags: entity-framework, poco, code-first

I have a MVC3 website I have been playing with, and the database is quite well populated. I need to change the underlying models, but of course, the standard approach would drop all data. Having the CREATE SQL (so I can ensure all fields/relationships are in line with the models), and the calculated hash (so EF thinks the models match the database) would allow me to manually make changes to the database.

Is there a way to interrogate a DataContext (or some other object) to:
1. Get the SQL it *would* use to generate the dataschema; and
2. Get the ERM Metadata hash

I have considered some other migration options, but just want to explore this avenue.

Edit: This is EF4.1, and is running against SQL 2008 R2 if that is of any relevance.

Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with EF Migrations.  You'd need to upgrade your project to EF 4.3.  You'd use the "Update-Database -Script" ps command.

Here is a link to the ASP.Net team blog on it:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Pluralsight also has a course on it.  They also have a free trial.  http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents?courseName=efmigrations

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Please expand this answer to include the relevant parts of the linked text. This helps us fight link rot. If those links break, this answer loses all context and value.

Comment: Which part loses conntext?  The part where I give him the exact technology to solve his problem or the part where I give him the exact powershell command?  I can remove the links or delete the answer but that would seem to do a disservice to the OP.

Comment: tzerb- thanks for the post. the MSDN blog was very helpful- the pluralsight training not so much, as I couldn't (easily) sign up. The code-migration is a little bit "too" magical, but the last section on "how to generate the change SQL" is looking like precicely what I am after. Thanks.